# Collection Nested within Model is Not Bound by MVC 3 (Always null)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

I have a model that represents various information about a university in ASP.NET MVC 3 and Entity Framework 5.0. The model has an ICollection of another model, called TrendModel. This collection seems to never be stored/bound by MVC at any point, no matter what I do.

When I manually set this collection to something at run time (after it is retrieved from the database), the collection is of course no longer null, but whatever I seem to set it to and then store in the database, trends is always null when I retrieve it from the database.

UniversityModel:

```
public class UniversityModel
{
    [Key]
    public string univ_id { get; set; }

    public string ipeds_id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public bool religious { get; set; }

    #region Location Information

    public string city { get; set; }
    public string state { get; set; }
    public string urbanization { get; set; }
    public double latitude { get; set; }
    public double longitude { get; set; }

    #endregion

    public ICollection<TrendModel> trends { get; set; }
}
```

TrendModel:

```
public class TrendModel
{
    [Key]
    public string id { get; set; }
    public ushort year { get; set; }
    public uint? capacity { get; set; }
    public uint? rate { get; set; }
    public uint? meals { get; set; }
    public bool? forProfit { get; set; }
    public bool? control { get; set; }
    public string degree { get; set; }
    public bool? landgrant { get; set; }
    public bool? athletic { get; set; }
    public string calendar { get; set; }
    public bool? required { get; set; }
}
```

Not sure if it is relevant, but if I put in a constructor for UniversityModel that sets trends to an empty list, then trends is no longer null and is an empty list.

Is this a model binding issue, or a post issue or something? Sorry if I'm completely off-base, I'm pretty new to MVC and ASP.NET.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turn out, the issue was fixed simply by me enforcing lazy loading on the trends, so the property now reads:

```
public virtual ICollection<TrendModel> trends { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

you haven't included a foreign key in your trend model.try adding `univ_id` in your `TrendModel` class.

```
public class TrendModel
{
    [Key]
    public string id { get; set; }
    .
    .
    .
    [ForeignKey("univ_id")]
    public string univ_id   {get;set;}
}
```