# How to keep a collection of items for dropdown list in MVC model?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, model

to keep things simple, I have a model Survey with the following properties:

```
class SurveyItem {
    public string Question { get; set; }
    public string SelectedAnswerCode { get; set; }
    public List<Answer> Answers { get; set; }
}
```

where Answer is like:

```
class Answer {
    public int AnswerCode { get; set; }
    public string AnswerText { get; set; }
}
```

Answers is used to build a dropdown listbox of possible answers for (a user selects one)

In my View I use a Model of IEnumerable
where for each question I have a list of answers to choose from.

I prefill this collection and pass to my View. When I click submit, it goes back to the controller for validation. If the model is not valid, I pass it to the same View for a user to fix his answers, like usual.

**Question** - Answers collection used for dropdown list is not preserved in the model when I submit. I use HiddenFor, EditorFor and DropDownListFor for single value properties, but, how do I keep a collection of possible answers in the Model?

P.S>

Thanks.

P.S. I am using single line code @Html.DropDownListFor to render the dropdown in my EditorTemplate:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedAnswerCode, 
new SelectList(Model.Answers, "AnswerCode", "AnswerText", 0))
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to add `virtual` to the Answers declaration.

```
class SurveyItem {
    public string Question { get; set; }
    public string SelectedAnswerCode { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Answer> Answers { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, didn't help. Not sure how this could help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13749631/collection-nested-within-model-is-not-bound-by-mvc-3-always-null/13749809#13749809

Comment: You may need to add a foreign key.  Something like QuestionId in both classes. EF should then look for all the Answers with same QuestionId as whatever question you are iterating through.

Comment: Thanks, but these are View Models, not EF entities. 
There are no foreign keys here.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to do the trick: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETWireFormatForModelBindingToArraysListsCollectionsDictionaries.aspx

Basically in your view do something like this:

```
@for(int i = 0; i < Model.Answers.Count; i++)
            {
                @Html.Hidden(string.Format("Answers[{0}].AnswerCode", i), Model.Answers[i].AnswerCode)
                @Html.Hidden(string.Format("Answers[{0}].AnswerText", i), Model.Answers[i].AnswerText)

                @Html.RadioButton("SelectedAnswerCode", Model.Answers[i].AnswerCode)
                @Model.Answers[i].AnswerText
            }
```

**EDIT:**

Alternatively, you can create your own HtmlHelper extension. For example:

```
public static class CustomHtmlHelperExtensions
    {
        public static MvcHtmlString HiddenForSurveyAnswers(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, IEnumerable<Models.Answer> answers)
        {
            var html = new StringBuilder();

            int index = 0;
            foreach (var answer in answers)
            {
                html.AppendLine(htmlHelper.Hidden(string.Format("Answers[{0}].AnswerCode", index), answer.AnswerCode).ToString());
                html.AppendLine(htmlHelper.Hidden(string.Format("Answers[{0}].AnswerText", index), answer.AnswerText).ToString());
                index++;
            }

            return MvcHtmlString.Create(html.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Then add an @using YourMvcApplicationNamespace to the top of the view and then use the extension like:

```
@Html.HiddenForSurveyAnswers(Model.Answers)
```

Comment: Thanks, but I am using single line code @Html.DropDownListFor to render the dropdown in my Editor Template. Please see > P.S.

Comment: @Sigourney_Weaver see my edit above on creating your own HtmlHelper extension to output the extra hidden fields

Answer (score 0):

With MVC, you can write an Editor Template to preserve the `Model.Answers` as well :)

Save a view named `Answer.chtml` in `\Views\Shared\EditorTemplates`.

Add the following code:

```
@model Answer          
@Html.HiddenFor(item => item.AnswerCode) 
@Html.HiddenFor(item => item.AnswerText)
```

Then in you original view, add it:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Answers)
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedAnswerCode, new SelectList(Model.Answers, "AnswerCode", "AnswerText", 0))
```

In this manner you don't have to worry about writing `foreach` statements or worry about their ids.
Hope it helps.